# How can I know if a number is contained in another in java?

Tags: java, integer

How can I know if a number is contained in another in java without converting to string? for example, if i put 123456 and 234 i should print true, but if i put 678 and 34 it should print false.

Comment: Check the length of "contained integer" and accordingly read that many characters from the number, e.g. 34 in 1234 would be either at 12, 23, 34 - only three traversal required.

Comment: It's important to note that this isn't about _numbers_; it's about _the decimal representation of numbers_. You're looking for _subsequence matching_ and will need to derive the relevant decimal digits yourself.

Comment: It would be easier and more efficient to convert them to strings and do the check then.

Comment: Using mod and divide operations repeatly can find the answer you want. Takes your first example as illustration: 123456 mod 1000 is 456 (not match), 12345 mod 1000 is 345 (not match), 1234 mod 1000 is 235 (match found).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The algorithm to find if `a` contains `b` could be as follows:

1. Find the power of 10 `p` closest to `b` to review the last digits of `a` using modulo operation.
2. While `a >= b`, check if the remainder of `a % p` or `a` are equal to `b`; if not, divide `a` by 10 (decimal right shift):

```java
static boolean aContainsB(int a, int b) {
    a = Math.abs(a);
    b = Math.abs(b);
    int p = 1;
    while (p <= b) {
        p *= 10;
    }
    
    boolean contains = a == b;
    while (!contains && a >= b) {
        contains = a % p == b || a == b;
        a /= 10;
    }
    return contains;
}
```

Tests and output:

```java
int[][] tests = {
    {234, 234}, {123, 234}, {123, 23}, {1234, 23}, {12345, 12},
    {325, 1}, {210, 1}, {123, 1}, {211, 1}, {210, 10},
    {91019, 10}
};

for (int[] t : tests) {
    System.out.printf("%d contains %d ? %s%n", t[0], t[1], aContainsB(t[0], t[1]));
}
```

Output

```
234 contains 234 ? true
123 contains 234 ? false
123 contains 23 ? true
1234 contains 23 ? true
12345 contains 12 ? true
325 contains 1 ? false
210 contains 1 ? true
123 contains 1 ? true
211 contains 1 ? true
210 contains 10 ? true
91019 contains 10 ? true
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are masochist, you can put your string of number into `List`/`Table` (one number to one indexed cell using `for` loop) and implement `contains()` method like for `String` objects. 
But better and easier way is convert `int` to `String` and use String's `contains()'.

```java
int a = 123456;
boolean contains = String.valueOf(a).contains("234");
```

Why do you don't want to convert to `String`?

Comment: You are still converting to String.

Comment: Its part of a school project, not using strings is part of the rules.

Comment: Okay, in a next time please write it in your question ;) Look at Spectric's answer. Is it helpful for you?